# Laravel: get user's friends where user_id or friend_user_id equals 3

Tags: sql, laravel, eloquent

I have two tables:
users: id, name;
friends: id, user_id, user_friend_id, approved;

I need to get all users where approved=0 for user_id = 3 or user_friend_is = 3 .

Comment: Google : SQL Laravel joins .

Comment: Thank you, it helped. I'm kinda new in sql joins stuff.

Answer (score 0):

Try this

```
DB::table('users')->join('friends','users.id','=','friends.user_id')
                  ->where('users.approved',0)
                  ->where(function($query){
                    $query->orWhere('users.user_id',3)
                          ->orWhere('users.user_friend_is',3)  
                   })->select('users.*')->get();
```

It will select all users where approved=0 and (user_id = 3 or user_friend_is = 3)

Hope this will help.